# Duplicates with MATCH/ROW in Excel

Tags: excel, match, row, lookup

I am using the following formula to find the original row number of values (dates) reorganized in a separate column.

`=MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$5,0)+ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1`

Unfortunately, my data sets contain duplicate values (dates) which outputs duplicated original row numbers. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this (to memory). You would need to add some sort of identifier to each row, eg. an ID, so you would have A:ID, B:Dates, C:Ordered ID, D:Ordered Dates. Then you would have the match look at the ID as well to determine where it came from

Comment: Can I ask why you are reordering like this though? To me it seems very silly to have data from different entities appearing on the same row. Typically you would want to just create a table/filter, and then have the rows sorted based on that. I would personally recommend this approach

Comment: You can do this with sorted data but not with unsorted data. 2018-07-20, 2018-03-10, 2018-08-25 is unsorted.

Comment: That's why I would suggest using a table or filter. That way it is always sorted and can be sorted easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$5)/($A$2:$A$5=B2),COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2))
```

[image]